# Polymer-Dart 1.0 dom-if not working

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

So I was trying to use the `<template is="dom-if">` but I just cannot make it work.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{row}}" as="project">
   <template is="dom-if" if="{{project == null}}">
      <span>Untitled project</span>
   </template>
   <template is="dom-if" if="{{project != null}}">
      <span>{{project.name}}</span>
   </template>
 </template>
```

For some reasons, I never get shown `Untitled project` although there are 2 elements which are `null`.

Are the expressions just not yet available in the developer preview of Polymer-Dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Polymer-Dart, but in Polymer 1.0 expressions are no longer supported ([docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#expressions-in-binding-annotations)).

You could use [computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed) to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually just use a simple {{project}} and {{!project}} binding. `!` is one of the only expressions allowed in polymer 1.0. It uses JS falsyness so a null value will be "false", but so will an empty list/etc.

You may also need to explicitly initialize the value to null in your ready method as well:

```
ready() {   if (project == null) set('project', null); }
```

Basically, for initial values of `null` we actually send undefined to the js side. However bindings wont run at all for undefined values, so you need to then explicitly assign `null` to ensure the dom-ifs will evaluate the expression. We do this to avoid an extra change notification for each property when each element starts up.